# Datatable: apply different formatStyle to each column

Tags: r, shiny

I want to apply `formatStyle` function to different columns in my table. I can easily apply the same style to all the columns, or to some subset of columns, e.g.

```
divBySum <- function(x) x/sum(x)

  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(mutate_each(mtcars, funs(divBySum)),
      options = list(searching = FALSE,
                     paging = FALSE,
                     dom = 't'),
      rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatStyle(colnames(mtcars),
                  background = styleColorBar(c(0, 1), 'lightgray'),
                  backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                  backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                  backgroundPosition = 'center') %>%
      formatPercentage(colnames(mtcars))
  )
```

However I would like to apply *different* `formatStyle` to each of the columns. For example, I would like to define maximal length of bar to `styleColorBar(c(0, max(x)), 'lightgray')`, where `x` is a column, or different colors for them.

I would like to do this with some function that takes as input a vector of column names. Is there any nice, clever way to do this?

Comment: I wonder if `tagList` could be used here? https://github.com/hrbrmstr/vegalite/issues/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `mapply` for this and loop through the columns to add whatever color you want, here's an example:

```
data <- datatable(mtcars)    

mapply(function(column,color){
        data <<- data %>% formatStyle(column,
                                      background = styleColorBar(c(0, max(mtcars[[column]])), color),
                                      backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                                      backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                                      backgroundPosition = 'center')
},colnames(mtcars),rep_len(c("green","red","yellow"),length.out = ncol(mtcars)))
```

Comment: do i reproduce wrongly or is this approach not working anymore?

Comment: @TonioLiebrand Yes it does not work anymore.