# Highlighting the maximum value of each column of data frame in R

Tags: r, colors, datatable

I have a `data.frame` in `R` :

```
p=structure(list(WSbin01 = c(214.98151752527, -46.9493685420515, 
154.726947679253), WSbin02 = c(1093.46050365665, 420.318207941967, 
927.97317496775), WSbin03 = c(2855.24990411661, 2035.57575481323, 
2662.2595957214), WSbin04 = c(5863.91399544626, 4881.81544665127, 
5625.17650575444), WSbin05 = c(9891.70254019722, 8845.32506336827, 
9666.14583347469), WSbin06 = c(14562.1527820802, 13401.1727730953, 
14321.601249974), WSbin07 = c(19091.1307681137, 18003.2115315665, 
18903.0179613827), WSbin08 = c(24422.7094972645, 23694.5453703207, 
24357.8071162775), WSbin09 = c(30215.4088114124, 30214.3195264298, 
30310.242671113), WSbin10 = c(36958.2122031382, 37964.9044838778, 
37239.6908819524), WSbin11 = c(41844.810779792, 43701.2643596447, 
42343.7442683171), WSbin12 = c(37616.8187087318, 39348.3188777835, 
38178.9009247311), WSbin13 = c(20953.0973658833, 21720.1930292221, 
21251.8654076726), WSbin14 = c(7155.3786781173, 7262.61983182254, 
7233.60584469268), WSbin15 = c(2171.61052809769, 2120.97045661101, 
2173.49396732091), WSbin16 = c(779.72276608943, 745.52198490267, 
767.81436310063)), .Names = c("WSbin01", "WSbin02", "WSbin03", 
"WSbin04", "WSbin05", "WSbin06", "WSbin07", "WSbin08", "WSbin09", 
"WSbin10", "WSbin11", "WSbin12", "WSbin13", "WSbin14", "WSbin15", 
"WSbin16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I would like to set a background color for the maximum value of each column.
Using `DT::datatable` would return the table but I don't know how to set the `formatStyle` parameters to return the max value in each column in different color.

Furthermore, I have a vector `z= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1)` . I wanna have the background color in each column like if `z[i]=1` column `i` should be green, if `z[i]=2` then column `i` should be red and if `z[i]=3` the column `i` should be blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining parts of the dt guide (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) and this q ([Datatable: apply different formatStyle to each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795010/datatable-apply-different-formatstyle-to-each-column)), I get this:

```
colors <- apply(col2rgb(rainbow(n=ncol(p))),2,function(x)paste0("rgb(",paste(x,collapse=","),")"))
data <- datatable(p)
sapply(c(1:ncol(p)),function(x){
  data <<- data %>% formatStyle(colnames(p)[[x]],backgroundColor = styleEqual(max(p[[x]]), colors[x]))
})
data
```

[image]
The answer to your second q is similar-

```
z= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1)
colors <- apply(col2rgb(rainbow(n=max(z))),2,function(x)paste0("rgb(",paste(x,collapse=","),")"))
data <- datatable(p) 
sapply(c(1:ncol(p)),function(x){
  data <<- data %>% formatStyle(
    colnames(p)[[x]],
    backgroundColor = colors[z[x]]
  )
})
data
```

Comment: How should I modify the code if I have a vector like `z=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,1)`, if `z[i]=1` then column` i `should have  color=green, if `z[i]=2` then column `i` should have color =red and if `z[i]=3`, then column `i `should have color =bule

Comment: If z is a column in your dataframe, then it looks like the example under heading 2 https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Comment: No, It is not in my dataframe !

Comment: @user9112767 - Edited the answer above to address your second Q. Let me know if it doesn't do the trick.